# How to append a select dropdown to a HTML DataTable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatables

I have created a website mainly using HTML, CSS, PHP and MYSQL and I added a select dropdown with roles for to users to choose from. I need it to be on every row of users in the table. I have successfully gotten tabledit working on the site, but I am not sure how to append this dropdown to the Roles column.

This is how the HTML is set up

```
<body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!--        <div class="panel-heading">Sample Data</div>-->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="sample_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Approval</th>
                        <th>Roles</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--SELECT DROPDOWN LIST-->
<select id="test">
    <?php
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $count ; $a++){
        ?>

        <option value="1"><?php echo($roles[($a-1)]);?></option>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<!--//////////////-->
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "order" : [],
            "ajax" : {
                url:"FetchUserTable.php",
                type:"POST"
            }
        });

        $('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function(){
            $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
                url:'ActionUserTable.php',
                dataType:'json',
                columns:{
                    identifier : [0, 'user_id'],
                    editable:[
                        [1, 'first_name'],
                        [2, 'last_name'],
                        [3, 'email'],
                        [4, 'admin_approved', '{"1":"Approved","2":"Disapproved"}']
                        // [5, 'role_id']
                    ]
                },
                restoreButton:false,
                onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if(data.action == 'delete')
                    {
                        $('#' + data.id).remove();
                        $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: What's "an HTML jquery table"? Do you mean https://datatables.net/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [render option on the column definitions](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to render what ever you want. In the render function you have access to the row and the entire data object.

```js
$(function() {
  let $tbl = $('#sample_data'), $select = $('#select-box')

  let data = [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$3,120"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Director",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$5,300"
    ]
  ]

  $tbl.DataTable({
    data: data,

    columns: [
      null, null, null, null, {

        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return $select.html() + `Use this to select "${data}"`
        }
      },
      {
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return $select.html() + `Use this to select "${data}"`
        }
      },
    ]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!--        <div class="panel-heading">Sample Data</div>-->
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="sample_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Approval</th>
              <th>Roles</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none;" id="select-box">
    <select>
      <option>Role 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to add a row in [**datatables.net**](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)...

> ```
>    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
>
>        t.row.add( [
>            counter +'.1',
>            counter +'.2',
>            counter +'.3',
>            counter +'.4',
>            counter +'.5'
>        ] ).draw( false );
> ```

So, in your case, within `onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`, we should just be able to change this, `$('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();`, to....

```
var t = $('#sample_data').DataTable();
t.row.add([
    $('#test').html()
]).draw(false);
t.ajax.reload();
```

This is basically doing what your code was doing before, but now you're also calling the `.row.add()` on the `DataTable()`.

Comment: Thank you so far, but the reason why I am using HTML DataTable is for the extras such as limit per page, and search box that it includes. When using  HTML DataTable, your answer cannot be applied unfortunately

Comment: @JoseLuisLandivar Ah, I think I understand now!  Do you think this would work?  (I'll update my answer, if so.)  After `$('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();`, try: $('#sample_data').find('tbody').html('<tr><td>' + $('#test').html() + '</td></tr>');`?  This should cause it to reappend after the datatables success handler, or let me know if I'm wrong?  That seems like it should work?

Comment: after implemented the suggested changes, I get this error message: ```DataTables warning: table id=sample_data - Requested unknown parameter '5' for row 0, column 5.``` It goes away when I comment out <th>Roles</th>. 

About hiding using css I'm using <select id="test" style="display:none">.

Comment: I'm looking at [datatables.net: Add rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).  It seems like all you may need is just `$('#sample_data').row.add([$('#test').html()])`?, or maybe the same thing without the ending `.html()` call?  I'll update the answer if that's right.

Comment: added it like this you mean:
```  onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if(data.action == 'delete')
                    {
                        $('#' + data.id).remove();
                        $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        $('#sample_data').find('tbody').html('<tr><td>' + $('#test').html() + '</td></tr>');
                        $('#sample_data').row.add([$('#test').html()]);
                    }
                }```

Comment: Oh, I meant, the *only* change you need should be the `.row.add` code.  You can remove the other changes that don't work.  That should work, with only `.row.add`, does it or no?

Comment: So far it still does not work. I keep getting the same error. Maybe you could update your answer once again and I could try it

Comment: Thanks for your patience, updated now!  Third times the charm.

Comment: Unfortunately, the column does not get added to the table.

Comment: The only thing I can think of trying to do is doing the same thing for the other line with the `datatable` call.  The official documentation that I linked is clear, but I'm sure I'm just misapplying it to this case.  If you had a half-working, online sandbox demo version, it would be much clearer for both of us to see that my fix is/is not working.

Answer (score 0):

its not a proper solution but it will resolve your issue. First select your roles html

```
var emelnt = $('#test');
//now append to table td
$('table tbody td:nth-child(6)').html(emelnt);
//you can also use a function to first get role id from table each row then create your select here in js and the append it to html so then your roles drop down will be selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using [`DataTable`](https://datatables.net/) or [`Tabledit`](http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit), you seem to be mixing them for some reason. I'm not sure if this is a good idea to start with. I suggest picking one over the other. This answer focuses on `Tabledit`.

Since the table is essentially created and managed by [`Tabledit`](http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit) you should provide the data there. You currently already use a select for admin approval:

> ```js
> [4, 'admin_approved', '{"1":"Approved","2":"Disapproved"}']
> ```

Your role select can be created in a similar manner. Since the structure of `$roles` is not shared I will assume that it is an array with string values. First create a variable `roles` within your `<script>` tags.

```js
const roles = <?php echo json_encode($roles); ?>;
```

Then add the column to the `columns.editable` setting:

```js
[4, 'admin_approved', '{"1":"Approved","2":"Disapproved"}'],
[5, 'role', JSON.stringify(roles)]
```

---

You might have to convert the structure of `$roles` to create the correct JSON output. Here are some example results:

Example #1

```js
// assumed <?php echo json_encode($roles); ?> output
const roles = ["role A", "role B"];
```

Creates:

```html
<option value="0">role A</option>
<option value="1">role B</option>
```

Example #2

```js
// assumed <?php echo json_encode($roles); ?> output
const roles = {"role_a": "role A", "role_b": "role B"};
```

Creates:

```html
<option value="role_a">role A</option>
<option value="role_b">role B</option>
```